# Small plastic ring obstructing the front facing camera on Samsung Galaxy s5

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-5, touchscreen, front-camera

there. 
I am hoping to take apart a Samsung Galaxy s5.
The trouble is that there is small black ring that has displaced and it is partially covering the front facing camera. 
I am not completely sure what caused this.

If it were my phone I would not be too worried about taking it apart. 
I want to make sure I understand what I need to do.

Here is a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yPN80hPjSb0) I found that disassembles the phone. I believe that up until about 2:40 in that video is all I really need to do to get access to the front-facing camera and the displaced ring.
Hopefully that will provide enough space to move the ring back in to place.

What I am looking for is an answer to the following question. 
In order to remove the screen I need to heat the phone up so as to loosen the glue.

*When I go to put the screen back on, will re-heating the phone be sufficient to make the original glue set again? Or will I need to buy some replacement glue in order for the screen to sit securely again?*

Perhaps someone out there has some experience with this. Cheers!